# sqlplus is not starting

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, redhat

I have a strange error on a Red Hat machine.

InstantClient is installed in and ORACLE_HOME is set to /opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/
The user which installed the client was oracle:oinstall. My user (itweb) is not able to run sqlplus in the .../bin folder.
Whenever I try it just sits there and does nothing. No error, no output, nothing. I have to CTRL-C out of it:

```
[host]:itweb:/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/bin $ ./sqlplus
^C
```

I then added ORACLE_HOME to my path but that did not change anything. I then checkes the output of ps while sqplus is waiting. The processstatus is D, waiting uninterruptable.

The filepermissions:

```
-rwxr-x--x. 1 oracle oinstall     8999 Oct 14 16:13 sqlplus
```

I was wondering why there is no r+o set. But maybe that is okay.

Any suggestions?

Edit: As suggested here is the output of strace:

```
[host]:itweb:/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/bin $ strace ./sqlplus
execve("./sqlplus", ["./sqlplus"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x601000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7ffd000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/tls/x86_64/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffffffddf0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/tls/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/tls", 0x7fffffffddf0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/x86_64/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffffffddf0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\370\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1477446, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1997344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7e15000
mprotect(0x7ffff7eee000, 1048576, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff7fee000, 57344, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd9000) = 0x7ffff7fee000
mmap(0x7ffff7ffc000, 2592, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7ffc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\344D\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=52690370, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7e14000
mmap(NULL, 43563144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff5488000
mprotect(0x7ffff7a5a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff7c59000, 1662976, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25d1000) = 0x7ffff7c59000
mmap(0x7ffff7def000, 149640, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7def000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libnnz11.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\324\4\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=7955322, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3979200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff50bc000
mprotect(0x7ffff5345000, 1044480, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff5444000, 270336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x288000) = 0x7ffff5444000
mmap(0x7ffff5486000, 6080, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff5486000
mprotect(0x7fffffffe000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC|PROT_GROWSDOWN) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=58580, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 58580, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff50ad000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r@\226<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22536, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c96400000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c96400000
mprotect(0x3c96402000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c96602000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3c96602000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p>\0\227<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=598680, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff50ac000
mmap(0x3c97000000, 2633912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c97000000
mprotect(0x3c97083000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c97282000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x82000) = 0x3c97282000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\\\300\226<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=145720, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c96c00000, 2212768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c96c00000
mprotect(0x3c96c17000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c96e17000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x3c96e17000
mmap(0x3c96e19000, 13216, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c96e19000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p@\200\227<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=116368, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c97800000, 2198192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c97800000
mprotect(0x3c97816000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c97a15000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x3c97a15000
mmap(0x3c97a17000, 6832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c97a17000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\355\201\226<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1922152, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff50ab000
mmap(0x3c96800000, 3745960, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c96800000
mprotect(0x3c9698a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c96b89000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x189000) = 0x3c96b89000
mmap(0x3c96b8e000, 18600, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c96b8e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\5@\226<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=5624, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c96400000, 2099840, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff4eaa000
mprotect(0x7ffff4eab000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff50aa000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff50aa000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff4ea9000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff4ea8000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff4ea7000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff4ea8700) = 0
mprotect(0x3c96b89000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c97a15000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c96e17000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c97282000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c96602000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c9621f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff50ad000, 58580)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7ffff4ea89d0)         = 11584
set_robust_list(0x7ffff4ea89e0, 0x18)   = 0
futex(0x7fffffffe6fc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7fffffffe6fc, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7ffff4ea8700) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x3c96c05ae0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3c96c0f500}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x3c96c05b70, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3c96c0f500}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x601000
brk(0x622000)                           = 0x622000
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x7ffff7ec06b4, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3c96832920}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, {0x7ffff7ec06b4, [ABRT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3c96832920}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 143360, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff4e84000
futex(0x3c966030ec, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libsqlplusic.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libociicus.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libociei.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/nls/data/lx1boot.nlb", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\0\0\0\3\0\3 \v\260W\0\0\230\363\216\0\0\0\0\0\1\0E\0\276\0\304\1\32\2,\2"..., 48) = 48
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 22400) = 22400
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/nls/data/lx00001.nlb", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\0\0\0\3\0\3 \v\267\3\0\0s\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Z\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 92) = 92
read(3, "\3\0\0\0\1\0\1\0\1\0`\0\0\0\4\0\6\0\10\0\n\0\20\0\30\0 \0(\0000\0"..., 859) = 859
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/nls/data/lx20001.nlb", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\0\0\0\3\0\3 \v9\33\0\0\215\21\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0Z\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 92) = 92
read(3, "\1\0\37\0\t\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 6877) = 6877
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/nls/data/lx10001.nlb", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\0\0\0\3\0\3 \vt\4\0\0\220\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0Z\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 92) = 92
read(3, "\3\0\0\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\1\0\2\0\2\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1048) = 1048
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0x646000)                           = 0x646000
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/nls/data/lx40011.nlb", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\0\0\0\5\0\3 \vaV\0\0aV\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0Z\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 92) = 92
read(3, "\0\0\0\0(\1\0\0,\1\0\0000\1\0\0004\1\0\0<A\0\0TF\0\0TV\0\0"..., 22021) = 22021
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/nls/data/lx40001.nlb", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\0\0\0\3\0\3 \v\20\177\0\0\354}\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0Z\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 92) = 92
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\354O\0\0L[\0\0004]\0\0L^\0\0Da\0\0"..., 32436) = 32436
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl//sqlplus/mesg/sp1us.msb", O_RDONLY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\25\23\"\1\23\3\t\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(3, 512, SEEK_SET)                 = 512
read(3, "m$\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(3, "\26\0-\0@\0R\0g\0\177\0\222\0\246\0\300\0\346\0\357\0\1\1L\1a\1\201\1\226\1"..., 36) = 36
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl//sqlplus/mesg/sp2us.msb", O_RDONLY) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "\25\23\"\1\23\3\t\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(4, 512, SEEK_SET)                 = 512
read(4, "\263\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(4, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(4, "\26\0*\0R\0h\0\201\0\236\0\350\0\374\0\n\1#\1?\1M\1\251\1\307\1\346\1\3\2"..., 124) = 124
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl//sqlplus/mesg/cpyus.msb", O_RDONLY) = 5
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(5, "\25\23\"\1\23\3\t\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(5, 512, SEEK_SET)                 = 512
read(5, "\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(5, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(5, "\t\0\f\0", 4)                  = 4
getcwd("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/bin", 256) = 40
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = -1 EAFNOSUPPORT (Address family not supported by protocol)
access("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/network/admin/sqlnet.ora", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/itweb/.sqlnet.ora", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/log", 0x7fffffffa730) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/itweb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0711, st_size=2048, ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 80479
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 6
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(6)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 6
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(6)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1721, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fff000
read(6, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1721
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7fff000, 4096)            = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=58580, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 58580, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 6, 0) = 0x7ffff7fff000
close(6)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=65928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2151824, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0) = 0x7ffff4c76000
mprotect(0x7ffff4c82000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff4e82000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0xc000) = 0x7ffff4e82000
close(6)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff4e82000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7fff000, 58580)           = 0
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1735, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fff000
read(6, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1735
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7fff000, 4096)            = 0
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib/libnss_sss.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=58580, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 58580, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 6, 0) = 0x7ffff7fff000
close(6)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_sss.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=30360, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2125744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0) = 0x7ffff4a6f000
mprotect(0x7ffff4a76000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff4c75000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0x6000) = 0x7ffff4c75000
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7fff000, 58580)           = 0
open("/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6806312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 6806312, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 6, 0) = 0x7ffff7fff000
uname({sys="Linux", node="[HOST]", ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 80479
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1735, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff50bb000
read(7, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1735
read(7, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(7)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffff50bb000, 4096)            = 0
brk(0x667000)                           = 0x667000
times({tms_utime=0, tms_stime=0, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1429219320
open("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl//rdbms/mesg/diaus.msb", O_RDONLY) = 7
fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
lseek(7, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(7, "\25\23\"\1\23\3\t\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 256) = 256
lseek(7, 512, SEEK_SET)                 = 512
read(7, "\371\311\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(7, 1024, SEEK_SET)                = 1024
read(7, "\210\273\353\273\363\273\373\273\4\274\16\274\26\274!\274)\2741\274<\274G\274T\274_\274k\274t\274"..., 192) = 192
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
open("/proc/self/fd/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
fcntl(8, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
brk(0x68f000)                           = 0x68f000
getrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, {rlim_cur=RLIM_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x7ffff6b51114, ~[ILL ABRT BUS FPE SEGV USR2 XCPU XFSZ SYS RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3c96c0f500}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [WINCH], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {0x7ffff6b51114, ~[ILL ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV USR2 STOP XCPU XFSZ SYS RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3c96c0f500}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x7ffff6b51114, ~[ILL ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV USR2 STOP XCPU XFSZ SYS RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3c96c0f500}, NULL, 8) = 0
stat("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/log", 0x7fffffffb690) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/itweb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0711, st_size=2048, ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 80479
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1735, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff50bb000
read(9, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1735
read(9, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(9)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffff50bb000, 4096)            = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="[host]", ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 80479
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1735, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff50bb000
read(9, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1735
read(9, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(9)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ffff50bb000, 4096)            = 0
access("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/network/admin/sqlnet.ora", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/intchg.ora", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/network/admin/intchg.ora", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/tnsnav.ora", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/network/admin/tnsnav.ora", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkdir("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb", 0775) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
chmod("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag", 0775) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1024, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1024, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/trace", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/alert", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/incident", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/metadata", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/metadata_pv", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/metadata_dgif", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/incpkg", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/sweep", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/lck", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/cdump", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/stage", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/metadata", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/metadata/ADR_CONTROL.ams", 0x7fffffff85b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/metadata/ADR_CONTROL.ams", 0x7fffffff8660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
times({tms_utime=0, tms_stime=0, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1429219322
times({tms_utime=0, tms_stime=0, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1429219322
open("/home/itweb/oradiag_itweb/diag/clients/user_itweb/host_2575675607_80/lck/AM_3216668543_3129272988.lck", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0660) = 9
fcntl(9, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(9, F_SETLK, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}
```

Comment: Can you run it under truss or strace so we can see which syscall's stalling?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you suggstion. I have added the strace output. It seems as if some files are not found. I am not sure if that is the problem because the oracle and root user are able to start sqlplus. I should add that the itweb-user is an ldap-user. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding this to the .profile:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl
PATH=/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
TNS_ADMIN=/var/opt/oracle
export TNS_ADMIN ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_BASE
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1; export NLS_LANG
ORA_NLS33=/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/ocommon/nls/admin/data; export ORA_NLS33
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib\
:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/ucblib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/ucblib:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I had the PATH and ORACLE_HOME set before but the rest is new.

Comment: There is an error in these profile: The variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set twice. Thje value set first is overridden by the second set. Especially the $ORACLE_HOME/lib cannot be found in the final LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I will  change this because I think this error was only intoduced to get a better format of the post

Comment: Instead of the env vars you are typically expected to source `. oraenv ` script (after setting the desired `ORACLE_SID=xxx`)

Comment: @eckes - IIRC - there is another Environment variable you have to set in order to skip being prompted for verification of ORACLE_SID/ORACLE_HOME.  The comments within the `oraenv` script should describe which one.